# Get x,y values from seaborn pairplot

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I would  like to extract the  data of a sns.pairplot, so the x,y values, to make recreate the plot in other software.

example:
`sns.pairplot(data, diag_kind="kde", hue="YEARS",  vars=["PRICE"])`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate through the diagonal axes, and access all the curves there. Such a curve has a label and x and y data:

```py
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
g = sns.pairplot(iris, hue="species",  vars=["petal_length"], diag_kind='kde')

for ax in g.diag_axes:
    for curve in ax.lines:
        print(curve.get_label())
        print(curve.get_xdata())
        print(curve.get_ydata())
```

Alternatively, you could get similar data without creating the plot:

```py
import seaborn as sns  # only needed for the demo dataset
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")

species = np.unique(iris["species"])
xmin, xmax = iris["petal_length"].min(), iris["petal_length"].max()
dx = 0.2 * (xmax - xmin)
xmin -= dx
xmax += dx
xs = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 200)
ys = np.zeros((len(species), len(xs)))
for i, specie in enumerate(species):
    kde = gaussian_kde(iris[iris["species"] == specie]["petal_length"])
    ys[i, :] = kde(xs)

# create a plot from the given data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i, specie in enumerate(species):
    plt.plot(xs, ys[i, :], label=specie)
    plt.fill_between(xs, ys[i, :], alpha=0.3)
plt.ylim(ymin=0)
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]